# Search in all mailboxes and accounts in Thunderbird

Tags: search, thunderbird

How can I search for a sender or string or whatever in ALL mailboxes in Thunderbird?

I use about 10 accounts and it is horrible to search every account separately.

Are there plugins for this?

I am using Thunderbird (in fact it is Debian 5, Icedove 2.0.0.24)

Answer (score 3):

You can do a small workaround:
[http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:*FAQs*:_Saved_Search](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Saved_Search)

Start by searching for your terms in a single folder.
In the results dialog, select "Save as Search Folder".

- Choose the parent folder that will hold this virtual folder.
- Where it says "Select the folders to search", click "Choose".
- Put checkmarks by any folders or entire accounts you'd like included.
- Click Create.

Your new virtual folder with the search results will be in your folder list according to the hierarchy you gave it.

Answer (score 2):

Eight years later, still no accepted answer, and I am just looking into the same thing :-)

[This page](https://www.lifewire.com/search-mail-thunderbird-1173119)
says

> Enable Fast and Universal Search in Mozilla Thunderbird
>
> To make sure fast indexed search is available in Mozilla Thunderbird:
>
> ```
> Select Tools | Preferences… or Thunderbird | Preferences… from the menu.
> Go to the Advanced tab.
> Open the General category.
> Make sure Enable Global Search and Indexer is enabled under Advanced Configuration.
> Close the Advanced preferences window.
> ```

Although I found it in `Tools/Options`.

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no extension to do that... The closest you could get would be to enable message archiving, set everything to archive to a single location, and then search that location.